# When does Static field inline initialization occur

Tags: java, classloader, static-members

Consider this:

```
Class A
{
   private static B b = new B();
   private static C c;

   static
   {
     c= new C();
   }
}
```

1. Is the initialization of `b` occur on class load?
2. Same question for initialization of `c`
3. What happends first initalization of `b` or `c`?
   **Please give me a reference for java docs regarding this issues if exists.**

Thanks

Comment: didn't found it and saw different answers regarding it so yes it will be nice if I have some reference to it

Comment: I just searched google for "When does Static field inline initialization occur java", which is exactly your title+java, and found an ***absolute treasure trove*** of information.

Comment: What would be the most obvious implementation/order, and why do you expect it is not?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Question is whether static variable that is initialized inline happens also in class load or after, if on class load then what the point of using static initializers(which are initialize on class load )

Comment: @JavaSa You are making it more complicated than it needs to be.  There is only static initialization and it occurs in the order it appears in the class. It is all done in one method which is called `<clinit>` in the byte code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class variables are initialized at class load time, [in textual order, as though they were a single block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), so b is initialized first then c, as noted in [step 9 of the Detailed Initialization Procedure defined in the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).

Comment: Thank you @JavaSa for the check. My apologies for the confusion; I was not directing my retort to you.

Answer (score 0):

The code block with the static modifier signifies a class initializer; without the static modifier the code block is an instance initializer.

Static initializers are executed in the order they are defined (top down, just like simple variable initializers) when the class is loaded (actually, when it's resolved, but that's a technicality).

Instance initializers are executed in the order defined when the class is instantiated, immediately before the constructor code is executed, immediately after the invocation of the super constructor.

[static block](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php)